# Trigger function only on "onclick"

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I need a function to run when an a tag is clicked. I am using the onclick="" but it seems that the function runs on page load, instead of waiting to run when the a tag is clicked on. How do I make it so the function only runs when the a tag is clicked?

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<a class="req_btn" onclick="conversionOne()">text</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function conversionOne() {
        alert("something"); 
    })();
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just remove the parentheses -> `function conversionOne() { alert("something"); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are invoking the function when the script loads using an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). Instead of this:

```
(function conversionOne() {
    alert("something"); 
})();
```

Do this:

```
function conversionOne() {
    alert("something"); 
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Thanks! Ill accept your answer once it allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a self-executing function.
Declare the function in the global scope without executing it.

```
function conversionOne() {
    alert("something"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function conversionOne() {
    alert("something"); 
})();
```

calling function like this will  work onload
Change this to

```
 function conversionOne() {
    alert("something"); 
};
```

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but Ori Drori posted this right before you. I will give you an upvote though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Doing this

```
(function(){
    /** code **/
})();
```

Means the code will be executed imediatelly.
in your case you want to create a function so you need this :

```
function conversionOne() {
    /** code **/
}
```

or

```
var conversionOne = function () {
    /** code **/
}
```